# Is there a Racket function that directs the user to a file in the Explorer?

Tags: file, racket, explorer

I’d like to use or write a function that takes a filename as an argument, which is then supposed to open the Explorer (or whatever Mac’s alternative is) and select that file – in this case, a .json file – so that the user can easily open and edit it. Is there a function in Racket I can use for that? Thanks.

Comment: For Windows this is [`shell-execute`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/subprocess.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._shell-execute%29%29).  I have no idea if there is a cross-platform equivalent (for macOS you could simply call `open` as a subprocess).

Comment: @ignisvolens Shell-execute works on Windows. Thanks! Could you elaborate on that second part? How would I call `open` as a subprocess?

Comment: As something like `(system* (find-exectuable-path "open") ...)`.  But this is unlikely to be the right approach to this.